# SQL Server File or Filegroup Creation Date

Tags: sql-server, datafile, filegroups

Is there a way to find out when a File was added to a filegroup in SQL Server. Or how to determine when a filegroup was created?
I've tried querying the sys tables looking at the lsn information and the file_guid.

thanks

Comment: Not really, unless you've had change data capture enabled throughout, in which case [`sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-cdc-map-lsn-to-time-transact-sql) *might* have the answer. The only other ways I can think of are not super reliable or precise, e.g. (a) created date in file explorer (but it could have been moved/attached later), (b) restoring old backups of the database going backward, if you have them, until that file is no longer included, or (c) first event in the default trace (not useful if it wasn't recent).

Comment: Thank you @AaronBertrand